# Spring Security Application login not working from with Jmeter

Tags: spring, spring-security, jmeter, csrf, blazemeter

I have an application using spring security , but when I am trying to login from Jmeter it always returns the login page. The jmeter scripts are loaded from jmeter.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your test flow is not correct, it missing the first request, you should build your scenario as follows:

- Open login page ([HTTP GET](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) Request)

  - Extract the [`_csrf` token](https://github.com/OWASP/CheatSheetSeries/blob/master/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.md#token-based-mitigation) value using a suitable [JMeter Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)
- Replace hard-coded (recorded?) value of the `_csrf` parameter with the [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) holding the value of the CSRF token.

More information: [How to Load Test CSRF-Protected Web Sites](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-csrf-protected-web-sites)

Comment: Hi Dmitri T, I have tried adding the first request as get login and the post-precessor, but still facing the same issue:

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWg9E.png
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9q0Mb.png
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp3K6.png

Comment: I don't think you have this token in the [HTTP response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers), my expectation is that you should switch the Regular Expression Extractor to look into `Body` instead. Also be informed that u[sing regular expressions to parse HTML is not the best idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2897748), [CSS Selector Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-cssjquery-extractor-jmeter) will fit better.